# Stream of multiple polls on one page - how to insert?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, polling

I have a page which displays a stream of polls (each poll has up to 4 answer options). This page is generated dynamically from a database, so it's pulling each poll question and the options from a mysqli_fetch_array.

What I'm having a hard time with is how to let users vote on the polls. I have each poll as its own form (with radio buttons for the options) and have it set to where the form is submitted upon clicking one of the radio buttons. The problem is, it ends up submitting every answer option on the page (I'm assuming because it's from $row['option']).

What is the best strategy to implement this kind of thing to where only the poll voted on will be submitted? Would like to use ajax if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Could you pls show your html-code and how do you fire your click_event?

**Ajax-with-jQuery:**

```
 <!-- in your head-section include jQuery -->
 <head>
  <script src ="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"> </script> 
 </head>
 <!-- your forms -->
 <form>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="foo"> Foo<br>
</form>
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="bar"> Bar<br>
</form>
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="foobar"> Foobar
</form>

<script >
 //wait until document is ready
 $(function() {
   //when these are the only radio-buttons on page you can select all and bind an click-event to it, 
  //else add a class to all radio-buttons and select like: $(".your_class") 
   $(":radio").click(function() {
     //get the url from the action-attribute of the form
     var value = $(this).val(),
         radioName = $(this).attr("name");
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/your_file.php",//the URL to your php-File
       data: { name: radioName, data: value}
     })
     .done(function( msg ) {
         alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
     });
   });
 });
</script>
```

In your php-file you can now save the POST normally with $_POST['name'] and $_POST['data'].
Everything that you output in this file will be the outtput of "msg" in the alert (in the ajax-request).
You could also output a json-string like :

```
 echo json_encode(array("error" => TRUE, "text" => "Data could not be saved!"));
```

Then in your done-function do:

```
 if(msg.error)
   alert("ERROR: " + msg.text);
 else
   alert("Your data has been saved :)");
```